# Rails 4.2 and Vagrant: get a blank page and nothing in the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4.1 app and I use Vagrant for developing it. Everything has been working fine but then I bumped the version to 4.2 and it seems to have broken somewhere. I can start the server just fine and get a 200 response when curling localhost from the VM but when trying to access from a web browser on the host I only get a blank page and nothing in the logs. I don't think the requests are actually going through to the VM but I have no errors or anything to help diagnose. This is repeatable for another person on my team and I've also tried with a completely vanilla application.

Has anyone experienced this or can help point to where I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're running into a change in Rack 1.6:
  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16578#issuecomment-52871088

Answer (score 1):

The default settings of Rails server in 4.2 are too secure for Vagrant port forwarding. There is a simple switch you can use to unbind the interface so Rails server behaves like it previously did.

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

If it get tiresome always unbinding the ip you can use a bash alias

```
alias rail='rails s -b 0.0.0.0`
```

and then just type

```
rail
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going in to my /etc/hosts file on my vagrant vm and changing the localhost address there.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

and then changing

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

to

```
0.0.0.0 localhost
```

Works like a charm. :)